# Throughput for PointyCastle's aes cbc?

Tags: flutter, dart, pointycastle

I'm trying to encrypt files with the PointyCastle package for flutter. I don't see any information anywhere for throughput benchmarks but when testing a 100mb file, it is taking about 10 seconds which seems very high compared to another flutter aes package or just any other encryption software.

I have created an example that will encrypt a whole file here. Am I implementing this incorrectly? Are you also getting very slow throughput with this example?

https://gist.github.com/hootyjeremy/06909cc0e37305ce5a7e13e1ed7a0522

*of course, you will have to substitute `inputFileName` and `outputFileName`.*

Comment: PC implements the AES round in software, where most other implementation use the AES round instructions available in modern processors, so of course its slower. Standard tradeoff of portability vs speed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But are you saying that modern processors have AES instructions built into them? I didn't know about this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set

Comment: Yeah, I googled it last night and found that. Thanks a lot.